# Card Layout not setting correct in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a Donation card for my site with the help of [this](https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/bartek-malanowski/1427306#html-tab-view). I am Almost done with code changes but unable to set the layout, it's not showing properly. All contents are overlapping. I tried to set a margin but that is not working.

```js
 $(function () {

  // Whitelist buttons in popovers
  var myDefaultWhiteList = $.fn.tooltip.Constructor.Default.whiteList
  myDefaultWhiteList.button = [];

  // Customizer popover
  var $tip = $('.btn-donate').popover({
    trigger: 'manual', // We don't want popover to launch when we don't need it :)
    html: true,
    offset: '-100px, 0',
    container: 'body',
    content: function () {
      return '<p>' + $(this).data('description') + '</p><button class="btn btn-sm btn-dismiss white-text z-depth-0 pr-0">Got it</button>';
    },
    template: '<div class="popover popover-blue" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-body"></div></div>'
  });

  // Manually show popover
  $tip.popover('show');

  // Handle popover dismiss
  $('.btn-dismiss').on('click', function () {
    $tip.popover('hide');
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #F0F0F0;
}

        :root {
  --yt-blue: #ea5b18; /* This is a custom color used by YouTube */
}

/* Custom card header */
.card-header {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-left: 16px !important;
  align-items: center;
  height: 48px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.donate-icon {
  display: flex;
  align-self: stretch;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 1.2rem;
  float: right;
  background: #ea5b18;
}

.donate-icon:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-50%,50%);
  background: #ea5b18;
}

.donate-icon i {
  color: #187415;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 8px;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.avatar {
  max-width: 50px;
}

.fundraiser {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.fundraiser .name {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.fundraiser .creator {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.fundraiser .details {
  flex: 1;
}

/* Ugly workaroung - sorry :( */
.btn-donate, .btn-donate:hover, .btn-donate:active, .btn-donate:focus {
  background: var(--yt-blue);
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

.sum {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.card-footer a {
  font-size: .785rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

/* Popover styles */
.popover-blue {
  background: var(--yt-blue);
  border-radius: 1;
}

.popover-blue .arrow:after {
  border-bottom-color: var(--yt-blue) !important;
}

.popover-blue .popover-body {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.btn-dismiss {
  float: right;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="card mt-4 mx-auto" style="max-width: 25rem;">
  <div class="card-header p-0">
    <span class="d-inline-block card-title mb-0">Donate now</span>
    <span class="donate-icon">
      <i class="fas fa-hand-holding-heart"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="fundraiser">
      <img src="https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/04/06/35/70/360_F_406357077_MWIAoFRKa7qmoLhr44pTraEzmF5rTFhf.jpg" class="avatar" />
      <div class="details px-2">
        <h3 class="name mb-0"><strong>Magic Logic</strong></h3>
        <span class="creator text-muted">paypal.me/MagicLogic</span>
      </div><a href="https://www.paypal.com/paypalme/MagicLogic" title="Donate">
      <button class="btn btn-md btn-donate z-depth-0" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" 
  data-description="You can buy me a cup of Coffee or something via PayPal.">Donate</button></a>
</div>
```

Trying to create something like this:

### [image]

Comment: Your question is too much influenced by the popover thing... if i run the code snippet i even get an error... 
As it is an html css problem pls only conclude that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it. Just needed to update the layout details in your Flexbox containers. This should get you going in the right direction. I will leave it up to you to figure out where you went wrong with displaying the circular hand with heart icon in the top right corner.

Secondly, you didn't provide the `<script>` tag to include jQuery in your project or a `<link>` to [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/). Which the page you provided [here](https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/bartek-malanowski/1427306#js-tab-view) uses to create the tooltip. After adding the jQuery `<script>`'s right before the closing `<body>` tag and including the Bootstrap `<link>` in the `<head>`, the tooltip displays correctly.

```js
$(function () {

  // Whitelist buttons in popovers
  var myDefaultWhiteList = $.fn.tooltip.Constructor.Default.whiteList
  myDefaultWhiteList.button = [];

  // Customizer popover
  var $tip = $('.btn-donate').popover({
    trigger: 'manual', // We don't want popover to launch when we don't need it :)
    html: true,
    offset: '-100px, 0',
    container: 'body',
    content: function () {
      return '<p>' + $(this).data('description') + '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-dismiss white-text z-depth-0 pr-0">Got it</button></p>';
    },
    template: '<div class="popover popover-blue" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-body"></div></div>'
  });

  // Manually show popover
  $tip.popover('show');

  // Handle popover dismiss
  $('.btn-dismiss').on('click', function () {
    $tip.popover('hide');
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #F0F0F0;
}

:root {
  --yt-blue: #ea5b18; /* This is a custom color used by YouTube */
}

/* Custom card header */
.card-header {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-left: 16px !important;
  align-items: center;
  height: 48px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgb(249, 249, 249);
  border: .1rem solid lightgray;
}

.card-title {
  padding: .25rem .6rem;
}

.donate-icon {
  display: flex;
  align-self: stretch;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 1.2rem;
  float: right;
  background: #ea5b18;
}

.donate-icon:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-50%,50%);
  background: #ea5b18;
}

.donate-icon i {
  color: #187415;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 8px;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.avatar {
  max-width: 50px;
}

.fundraiser {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: .1rem;
}

.fundraiser .details.px-2 {
  margin: 0 1rem 0 .5rem;
}

.fundraiser .name {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: .15rem 0;
}

.fundraiser .creator {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #555;
}

.fundraiser .details {
  flex: 1;
}

.btn-donate {
  margin-top: .1rem;
  padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
  border: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: .8rem !important;
  border-radius: .1rem;
  background: #ea5b18 !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}

.btn-donate, .btn-donate:hover, .btn-donate:active, .btn-donate:focus {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sum {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.card-footer a {
  font-size: .785rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

/* Popover styles */
.popover-blue {
  border-radius: 1;
}

.popover-blue .arrow:after {
  border-bottom-color: var(--yt-blue) !important;
}

.popover-blue .popover-body {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ea5b18;
  font-size: 1rem;
  height: 6rem;
}

.btn-dismiss {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  color: #fff !important;
  float: right;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.bs-popover-top > .arrow::after {
  border-top-color: #ea5b18 !important;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="card mt-4 mx-auto" style="max-width: 25rem;">
  <div class="card-header p-0">
    <span class="d-inline-block card-title mb-0">Donate now</span>
    <span class="donate-icon">
      <i class="fas fa-hand-holding-heart"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="fundraiser">
      <img src="https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/04/06/35/70/360_F_406357077_MWIAoFRKa7qmoLhr44pTraEzmF5rTFhf.jpg" class="avatar" />
      <div class="details px-2">
        <h3 class="name mb-0"><strong>Magic Logic</strong></h3>
        <span class="creator text-muted">paypal.me/MagicLogic</span>
      </div><a href="https://www.paypal.com/paypalme/MagicLogic" title="Donate">
      <button class="btn btn-md btn-donate z-depth-0" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" 
  data-description="You can buy me a cup of Coffee or something via PayPal.">Donate</button></a>
</div>
    <!-- You must include the jQuery and Bootstrap scripts  -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help...but it not showing pop-up on `Donate` as it showing here https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/bartek-malanowski/1427306#html-tab-view

Comment: That's because jQuery isn't being referenced properly in your HTML as the error in the console clearly states.

Comment: @MagicduetoLogic The tooltip displays correctly after including those missing jQuery and Bootstrap links/scripts. Feel free to upvote or mark my answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Comment: Wow nice...! Thank you so much...! can you please help me for padding `Donate Now` heading? It not showing properly I tried my self but not working.

Comment: @MagicduetoLogic Thanks for the upvote! I just added padding to the "Donate now" text so it matches the desired layout in the example you included.

Comment: Thank you so much for your all help...! Feel free to up vote question if you think question was good... :)

Comment: Your welcome! I think it was a good learning experience for you and that's what StackOverflow is all about so I believe it warrants an upvote. Happy coding!